# Using Python to sign into website, fill in a form, then sign out

Tags: python, html, forms, web, urllib

As part of my quest to become better at Python I am now attempting to sign in to a website I frequent, send myself a private message, and then sign out. So far, I've managed to sign in (using urllib, cookiejar and urllib2). However, I cannot work out how to fill in the required form to send myself a message.

The form is located at /messages.php?action=send. There's three things that need to be filled for the message to send: three text fields named name, title and message. Additionally, there is a submit button (named "submit").

How can I fill in this form and send it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fill form values in a web page via a Python script (not testing)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555234/fill-form-values-in-a-web-page-via-a-python-script-not-testing)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
import urllib
import urllib2

name =  "name field"
data = {
        "name" : name 
       }

encoded_data = urllib.urlencode(data)
content = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.abc.com/messages.php?action=send",
        encoded_data)
print content.readlines()
```

just replace `http://www.abc.com/messages.php?action=send` with the url where your form is being submitted

reply to your comment: if the url is the url where your form is located, and you need to do this just for one website, look at the source code of the page and find

```
<form method="POST" action="some_address.php">
```

and put this address as parameter for `urllib2.urlopen`

And you have to realise what `submit` button does.
It just send a `Http` request to the url defined by `action` in the form.
So what you do is to simulate this request with `urllib2`

Comment: Whoop, sorry. It's the page where the form is located. (continued in next comment thanks to my silly iPod)

Comment: (continued) Thanks! That looks like it will work. I'll try it in the morning - will that submit the form, too, or do I have to put something in the data list for "submit"?

Answer (score 16):

You can use mechanize to work easily with this. This will ease your work of submitting the form. Don't forget to check with the parameters like name, title, message by seeing the source code of the html form.

```
import mechanize
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.open("http://mywebsite.com/messages.php?action=send")
br.select_form(nr=0)
br.form['name'] = 'Enter your Name'
br.form['title'] = 'Enter your Title'
br.form['message'] = 'Enter your message'
req = br.submit()
```

Answer (score 14):

You want the [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) library. This lets you easily automate the process of browsing websites and submitting forms/following links. The site I've linked to has quite good examples and documentation.

Comment: :D I've got it installed now, I'll have a play around with it! Thanks :D

Comment: I am getting this error when I try to import mechanize:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#7>", line 1, in <module>
    import mechanize
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\WinPython-64bit-3.6.1.0Qt5\python-3.6.1.amd64\lib\site-packages\mechanize\__init__.py", line 119, in <module>
    from _version import __version__
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_version'

Answer (score 3):

Try to work out the requests that are made (e.g. using the Chrome web developer tool or with Firefox/Firebug) and imitate the POST request containing the desired form data.

In addition to the great mechanize library mentioned by Andrew, in case I'd also suggest you use [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) to parse the HTML.

If you don't want to use mechanize but still want an easy, clean solution to create HTTP requests, I recommend the excellend [requests](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests) module.

Answer (score 2):

To post data to webpage, use cURL something like this,

`curl -d Name="Shrimant" -d title="Hello world" -d message="Hello, how are you" -d Form_Submit="Send" http://www.example.com/messages.php?action=send`

The “-d” option tells cURL that the next item is some data to be sent to the server at http://www.example.com/messages.php?action=send