# Web scraping login reqs in Python (e.g. zoominfo)

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I am attempting to write a web scraping app for the website, zoominfo.com. However, I am having trouble getting past one major hurdle, the login procedures. I have looked at other 'web-scraping through login requirements' posts, but none seem to match up with zoominfo.com's system. If anyone would mind taking a look and offering some expertise, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Note that the specific website you pointed explicitly prohibits scraping in their T&C. For the general question of automatically filling out forms there are many many solutions, including `urllib2.urlopen`, `seleninum`, `qt4` etc. depending on your specific needs any of these could be used.

Comment: Are you suggesting that web-scraping zoominfo.com is impossible? or that with the use of one of those modules, such as seleninum or qt4, that it can be done? Also, if it is not possible, do you have any ideas for how to potentially get around that. thanks

Comment: Not only is it possible, it's relatively easy, I suggest doing a little googling and you'll find some useful information. For example, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8560959/using-python-to-sign-into-website-fill-in-a-form-then-sign-out . I would post an answer, but your question shows no attempt to solve it so I have nothing to work off (if you can post what you have thus far, I can help you more specifically but I'm not going to write code for you unless you pay me :) ).