# How to fill a textArea in an online form automatically using Python?

Tags: python, linux, forms, web-applications, mechanize

I am wondering how I can fill an online form automatically. I have researched it and it tuned out that, one can uses Python ( I am more interested to know how to do it with Python because it is a scripting language I know) but documentation about it is not very good. This is what I found:

[Fill form values in a web page via a Python script (not testing)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555234/fill-form-values-in-a-web-page-via-a-python-script-not-testing)

Even the "mechanize" package itself does not have enough documentation:

http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/

More specifically, I want to fill the TextArea in this page (Addresses):
http://stevemorse.org/jcal/latlonbatch.html?direction=forward

so I don't know what I should look for? Should I look for "id" of the the textArea? ?It doesn't look like that it has "id" (or I am very naive!). How I can "select_form"?

Python, web gurus, please help.

Thanks

Comment: Edited my answer. Have a look.

Answer (score 2):

See if my answer to the other question you linked helps:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5685569/711017

**EDIT:**
Here is the explicit code for your example. Now, I don't have mechanize installed right now, so I haven't been able to check the code. No online IDE's I checked have it either. But even if it doesn't work, toy around with it, and you should eventually get there:

```
import re
from mechanize import Browser
br = Browser()
br.open("http://stevemorse.org/jcal/latlonbatch.html?direction=forward")
br.select_form(name="display")
br["locations"] = ["Hollywood and Vine, Hollywood CA"]
response = br.submit()
print response.read()
```

Explanation: `br` emulates a browser that opens your url and selects the desired form. It's called *display* in the website. The textarea to enter the address is called *locations*, into which I fill in the address, then submit the form. Whatever the server returns is the string `response.read()`, in which you should find your Lat-Longs somewhere. Install mechanize and check it out.

Comment: I checked out your answer. I have not been able to figure it out. I have tried another package called twill which is apparently a wrapper around mechanics. It is slightly easier but I don't know for example how to click a button (is it the same as submit?)

Comment: Clicking a button to submit a form is the same as the submit, yes.