# How could I use python to sent data to the following website and get the data generated there back?

Tags: python, html, forms

I want to write a python code to fill the blanks in the following website [enter link description here](https://t-ict4d.ictp.it/nequick2/nequick-2-web-model), and then get the output(data at the end) sent back to me. I was trying using "requests" libraries but I could not make it work. Could anyone help? Thanks!!!

A sample data could be filled in the form looks like this:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iIJre.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sy8K3.png)

Comment: write REST client

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fill form values in a web page via a Python script (not testing)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555234/fill-form-values-in-a-web-page-via-a-python-script-not-testing)

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Unfortunately, we are not a code-writing or a homework service. Please provide a [mcve] as described in the link, including what you've tried so far and what went wrong with your attempts.